# how convert 0 value to empty Blank in crystal report

Tags: crystal-reports

I am using formula in crystal report for count value in raw but when count value is null formula show  zero  ...........................................................................................................................................................................................
like this [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1ilO.png)

I wanna show blank instead of 0

how can I do this

I am using this formula for count "P" or "V" or "C"

```
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D01});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D02});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D03});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D04});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D05});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D06});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D07});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D08});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D09});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D10});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D11});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D12});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D13});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D14});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D15});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D16});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D17});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D18});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D19});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D20});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D21});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D22});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D23});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D24});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D25});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D26});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D27});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D28});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D29});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D30});
EvaluateAfter({PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D31});

    Local StringVar D01;
    Local StringVar D02;
    Local StringVar D03;
    Local StringVar D04;
    Local StringVar D05;
    Local StringVar D06;
    Local StringVar D07;
    Local StringVar D08;
    Local StringVar D09;
    Local StringVar D10;
    Local StringVar D11;
    Local StringVar D12;
    Local StringVar D13;
    Local StringVar D14;
    Local StringVar D15;
    Local StringVar D16;
    Local StringVar D17;
    Local StringVar D18;
    Local StringVar D19;
    Local StringVar D20;
    Local StringVar D21;
    Local StringVar D22;
    Local StringVar D23;
    Local StringVar D24;
    Local StringVar D25;
    Local StringVar D26;
    Local StringVar D27;
    Local StringVar D28;
    Local StringVar D29;
    Local StringVar D30;
    Local StringVar D31;
    Local NumberVar i;
    Local NumberVar j;
    Local StringVar array x;
    D01:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D01};
    D02:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D02};
    D03:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D03};
    D04:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D04};
    D05:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D05};
    D06:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D06};
    D07:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D07};
    D08:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D08};
    D09:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D09};
    D10:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D10};
    D11:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D11};
    D12:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D12};
    D13:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D13};
    D14:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D14};
    D15:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D15};
    D16:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D16};
    D17:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D17};
    D18:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D18};
    D19:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D19};
    D20:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D20};
    D21:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D21};
    D22:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D22};
    D23:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D23};
    D24:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D24};
    D25:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D25};
    D26:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D26};
    D27:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D27};
    D28:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D28};
    D29:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D29};
    D30:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D30};
    D31:={PayRoll_database_sp_PresentTable_Result.D31};

    x:=[D01,D02,D03,D04,D05,D06,D07,D08,D09,D10,D11,D12,D13,D14,D15,D16,D17,D18,D19,D20,D21,D22,D23,D24,D25,D26,D27,D28,D29,D30,D31];
    j:=0;
    for i:=1 to Count(x) do
    (
    if x[i]="V" or x[i]="C" or x[i]="L"
    Then j:=j+1;
    );
    j
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have zeros in a report, you may want to show them as blanks.
**Right-click** on the relevant field and select **Format Field** from the shortcut menu that appears. On the **Number tab**, click **Customize**.

On the Number tab, check the **Suppress if Zero box**. Click OK twice. You will then have blanks instead of zeros.

[image: Custom Style menu]